# Daemon Tools Lite Error- Unable to add adapter

Tags: windows-7, laptop, iso-image, virtual-drive

I just got a ThinkPad T510 with Windows 7 Professional and I installed Daemon Tools Lite, but I keep getting an error when I run it:

> Unable to add adapter.

I can't load iso images, because there is no virtual drive. I tried starting it as an administrator, it tried to update the virtual devices, and it got the same problem. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, here is how I solved the problem for Windows 7:

1. Uninstalled Daemon Tools.
2. Uninstalled SPTD.
3. Removed legacy SPTD keys from the registry.
4. Re-installed SPTD **before** installing Daemon Tools.
5. Installed Daemon Tools Lite.

Here are the resources that I used:

1. For Daemon Tools SPTD issues: http://daemonpro-help.com/?id=932
2. This shows how to clean up the SPTD registry keys and install SPTD by itself (without Daemon Tools): [Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20201022093809/http://geekswithblogs.net/apopovsky/archive/2009/08/14/re-installing-daemon-tools-lite-and-sptd-on-windows-7.aspx)
3. You can download the latest SPTD by itself here: http://www.duplexsecure.com/en/downloads

Comment: Thanks for that, although you might have gone a little overboard. Windows 7 64-bit - All I had to do was install the latest version of SPTD (64-bit) manually, then re-install Daemon Tools and the problem was solved. No messing around in the registry needed.